# android - Scala OnClickListener AlertDialog

Tags: android, eclipse, scala, android-alertdialog

I create AlertDialog for android in scala IDE plugin eclips, I want to change my activity after clicking on the No button but I couldn't change it, I also don't have any error!!

would you please give me some hints, if I wrote it wrong

Thanks in advance! This is my first android app in scala

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Exit the camera")
                .setMessage("Do you want to try again?")
                .setPositiveButton("No", new View.OnClickListener {
                    println("Nooooo Print")
                    def onClick(dialog: View) {
                        println("No Print");
                        val intent = new Intent(ClaimBookActivity.this,   
 classOf[HomeActivity]);
                        startActivity(intent); 
                        println("No Class");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Yes", new View.OnClickListener {
                    println("yes Print")
                    def onClick(dialog: View) {
                        println("test")
                    }
                }).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote yor code a little bit and it starts second activity well:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setTitle("Exit the camera")
  .setMessage("Do you want to try again?")
  .setPositiveButton("No",
    () => {
      println("No Print")
      val intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
        classOf[NotMainActivity])
      startActivity(intent)
      println("No Class")
    })
  .setNegativeButton("Yes",
    () => {
      println("yes Print")
      println("test")
    }).show()
```

Add this code somewhere else

```
implicit def func2OnClickListenerDialog(func: () => Unit): DialogInterface.OnClickListener = {
    new OnClickListener() {
      override def onClick(dialog: DialogInterface , which: Int) = func()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your activity `HomeActivity` is at least recorded in the Makefile, else it will not fire and throw an error in the background. Because this activity was started in the background, it may not result in an error.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="Home activity" >
    </activity>
```

See [Starting an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for more details.

Else you might be editing a .class file if you are using the debugger? In that case, close the .class file and open the *.scala file.